# replace and increment integer value using a javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string

`XXXX Units[4].Test XXXX`

I would like to replace each occurrence of `Unit[x]` with `Unit[x+1]`.
I am trying to achieve this using a regular expression, as the name `Units` needs to be literally matched first.

I am trying something like this:

```
test.replace(/(?:Units\[|\_+)(\d+)/g, function(m, i) { return parseInt(m) + 1 })
```

My problem is that without positive lookbehind I cannot seem to match only the digits. I am trying to build the regex in such a way that only the digits form part of the capture group, and I can therefore replace them.

It's easy to do in c#, but the javascript match function works a little differently.

Despite the non capture specification of `(?:` the `Units[` seems to form part of the match. Since javascript does not support look behind, I am at a loss as to how to complete this.

Comment: The first argument to the callback  function is the **entire** match. The first group in the regex is the second argument.

Comment: `(?:` just means it's not in a capturing _group_, it's still in the overall substring that's parsed, and then your digits are in the first captured group.

Comment: Hello [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it's been a few weeks.

Comment: [Specifying a function as a parameter to `String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) this may be of help to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group the part before number and use that back-reference in replacement later:

```
test = test.replace(/(Units\[)(\d+)/ig, function($0, $1, $2) {
      return $1 + (parseInt($2)+1); })

//=> XXXX Units[5].Test XXXX
```

Note use of `$1` and `$2` in the callback function where `$1` represents value `Units[` and `$2` is the number after it.